# How to count occurrences of a string ex. "sometext" in multiple .gz files in a directory and its sub directories?

Tags: macos, terminal, grep, find, gzip

Got many log files (ex. name "FILENAME-10/00/00.log.gz") in multiple sub-directories upto 5 levels deep. I want to count the occurrence of "sometext" which is once in each log file after 4-5 lines. I want to use my mac/terminal.

I guess I could use cat/grep/find etc but don't know exactly how. Please help. I tried following:

```
$ find dir/ -type f -exec grep -H 'string' {} +
$ find . -iname '*.gz' -exec zgrep PATTERN {} +
```

Also tried `grep -0` and `cat *`.

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get what you mean! Please clarify. @JAL

Comment: Don't just ask for code, please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ahh ok. Updated in question

Comment: Did those not work? How did they not work?

Comment: Actually, I am very new to unix, don't know how to syntax properly. So sometimes it was bad command and other times it was like it printed each line of occurrence on the screen. Would be great if someone can tell me proper syntax to of the command including where to put the directory destination. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `zgrep -c` to give you the number of occurrences.